# Trouble including a HTML file which contains a tippy elememt in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, tippyjs

I am trying to use tippy to provide hover text on certain words within passages of text that will appear in a shiny app. To make it easier to edit long passages of instructonal text, rather than include the text directly in the shiny UI I have generated the instructions in separate RMarkdown files and then embedded the corresponding HTML files using `shiny::includeHTML()`.

The tippy hover texts work nicely in the rendered HTML but does not appear in the shiny app.

Calling tippy directly in the app does work, so that is an option, but if possible I would prefer to keep the long instructional text separate to the app file.

The .Rmd file (which produces the HTML) and the app.R file below illustrates the problem. Thank you for any suggestions.

**long_text.Rmd**

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(tippy)
library(shiny)
```

Regular HTML tags work:

```{r}
tags$p('Hello', tags$span(style="color:blue", 'world'))
```


But tippy does not:

```{r}
tippy('This works in the HTML file but not when embedded in the Shiny app', 'Uh oh')
```
````

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

ui <- fluidPage(

tags$p(tippy('Using tippy directly in the Shiny UI works fine', 'nice')),

htmlOutput('text')    
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$text <- renderUI(includeHTML('longText.html'))
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the HTML document as a fragment. The tool tips will not work on the knitted HTML fragment, but when you include the built HTML file it in the Shiny app, you'll see the tool tips.

```
 ---
 output: html_fragment
 ---
```

Comment: This solution worked thank you!

I'm not sure why but it only seems to work if there is some call to tippy directly within the app UI. so when I include `tags$p(tippy(NULL, NULL))` in the UI file it works, but if I remove that it stops working.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Loading it as a built HTML document, Shiny doesn't know there are dependancies, so it doesn't load the tippy libraries. As is, loading an empty tag as you have done may be the best solution. I'll see if there is another workaround that...

Comment: There used to be a function to load the libraries on demand `use_tippy()` but you can no longer use it in this version. You can use the function `tippy_class("tool-tip")` in the UI to set a css class for tippy, and that will load the libraries. I think this is better than adding an empty tag, less hacky.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I've updated to incluse tippy_class("tool-tip") as suggested. Thanks again for your quick response!

Comment: Glad that worked out! If this answer helped you, perhaps you can mark it as solved?